# Binding Gtk# NodeView to a IList?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gtk#, ilist

I've got a data object with a component in it that is an System.Collections.Generic.IList, and I'd like to reflect changes to that list into a Gtk# NodeView, so that when an item is added to the list, the NodeView will get a new item added to it.

How would I listen for changes to an IList?  I have considered wrapping the IList with a class that implements IList, delegates the requisite methods, and broadcasts an event when changing it's contents, but that seems like a lot of work for something that has probably already been solved by someone else.

Comment: This is the way I did it, I can provide a copy of the code if you're interested. I'd still be interested in hearing other people's input on the subject though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gtk.DataBindings](http://gtk-databind.sourceforge.net/) is wahat you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do System.Componen.BindingList or System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection exist in mono?

Comment: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection Exists, and I'm investigating it.